# Should we burn [Google]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Recently some others and I began to clean up [google](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) a bit. This started with retagging a number of question with [google-apps-script](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). Then we hit a wall. All of the questions that should have been retagged were, but we were left with <s>18</s> 14 questions that didn't seem to have a better tag than the extremely generic "Google". Several questions can be cleaned up by replacing it with [google-maps](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps), but there are a number of questions that still just don't fit in any of our other 6 google tags (not including [android](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android)).

- [google](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google)
- [google-app-engine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine)
- [google-apps-script](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)
- [google-maps](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps)
- [google-sheets](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)
- [google-chrome](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome)

As you can see by looking at the [wiki](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/google/info), our Google tag is very broad and i can't imagine that it's very useful as it is. It's only real use is a catch all for something related to google in some general way. It's not very well defined. I think it should go, but we're then left with the question of what do we use to tag these questions. [As I stated here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2130/41243), I think we have a couple of options.

1. Leave [google](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) alone. It's fine how it is. Retag what can be retagged and move on.
2. Replace it with a more specific, but still kind of catch all, [google-api](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-api) tag. This would give the benefit of specifically stating that this is code using one of Google's APIs and is not to be used for questions which are [related to Google through it's second cousin's ex-college roommate](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20462/a-program-that-mimics-t9-cell-messaging) and burn [google](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google). This would leave some google related questions without a tag saying so.
3. Burn [google](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) and introduce more specific tags where applicable, as they are needed. Tags such as [youtube-api](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api) and [google-drive-api](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api).

I tend to lean toward a combination of options 2 and 3, but I'm putting it to the community. Let's clean this up before it gets more out of hand than it already is.

**Updates:**

- More general, existing tags were applied wherever possible.
- Questions that could be, have been retagged with [google-maps](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps).
- [Questions using the Google Feed API](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=google+rss+is%3Aquestion) have been retagged with the generic [rss](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss) tag.
- [google-contacts-api](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-contacts-api) has been added.
- [gwt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gwt) has been added.
- There are currently 0 questions tagged [google](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google). We've burned it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 3:** Burn [google](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) and introduce more specific tags where applicable, as they are needed. Tags such as [youtube-api](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api) and [google-drive-api](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api).

Comment: After further review of the remaining google questions, I'm not sure we will need to introduce more than one or two new tags *at this time*.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 2:** Replace it with a more specific, but still kind of catch-all, [google-api](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-api) tag and burn [google](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google). This would give the benefit of specifically stating that this is code using one of Google's APIs and is not to be used for questions which are [related to Google through its second cousin's ex-college roommate](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20462/a-program-that-mimics-t9-cell-messaging). This would leave some Google related questions without a tag saying so.

Comment: -1, Google has so many APIs that this would essentially be meaningless. If a generic tag like that is wanted, option 4 would probably be better (Google's APIs have nothing more in common with each other than APIs from other vendors). Option 3 sounds like the best approach to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 4:** Give no special treatment to Google.  Introduce a generic tag such as [web-service-integration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-service-integration), which could apply equally well to Twitter, Amazon, Vimeo — any well known service that provides a web API.  That would remove the need for [google-drive-api] and [youtube-api] tags, for example.

For more interesting integrations, such as Google Chrome extensions, we could still have a [google-chrome](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) tag.

Comment: I like this, but I question how useful it would be in practice. Someone may want to follow questions about Twitter, but not Amazon.

Answer (score -5):

**Option 1:** Leave [google](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) alone. It's fine how it is. Retag what can be retagged and move on.

Comment: The problem will only get worse, as it's only a matter of time before Google becomes synonymous with all computing.