# Do we need a [payment-system] tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

We currently have 26 [credit card questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+credit+card) questions and 47 [payment questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+payment). I'm not sure how much overlap there is between the two. At least some of the credit card questions could be tagged with [validation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/validation), but I'm wondering if the site would benefit from a new [payment-system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment-system) tag. I'm thinking this would help our [search engine optimization](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-can-we-get-noticed-on-search-engines/2138#2138) and programmers looking into implementing such things.

What do you think? Good tag?

It seems there's some interest in this, but I'm unsure of a good name. Which would be best?

- [payment-system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment-system)
- [e-commerce](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce)
- ?

Comment: I don't have the materials yet for an answer, but what would the pros and cons be? If SEO is the pro, would you tag other domain-areas (like emailing, authentication) as well? What makes these tags not meta tags?

Comment: Well, we have an [tag:email] and an [tag:authentication] tag @Pimgd. We also have tags like [tag:fizzbuzz]. It's offers (IMO) a useful categorization.

Comment: Seems like a good tag then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would love this tag, I find all these questions and answers entertaining and educating.

The name itself is not too obvious, so perhaps some more thought could be put in the actual name.

[payments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payments), [currency](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency) or [financial](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/financial) might be broader and also have subjects like bitcoin.

Comment: Any suggestions? That was the best I could come up with.

Comment: @RubberDuck I've created a [tag:finance] tag.

Answer (score 1):

If code was related to a [payment-system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment-system) then I would agree that the tag was useful.

Credit cards are not a payment system though, so none of those questions would qualify.

[payment-system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/payment-system) would be things like Moneris, EFT, Paypal, etc. I would expect the tag to relate to the Wikipedia entry at least a little bit:

> The payment system is an operational network - governed by laws, rules and standards - that links bank accounts and provides the functionality for monetary exchange using bank deposits

I don't believe any Code Review questions referenced in the question have anything to do with payment systems, other than the following:

- [Thread-safe wrapper around WCF ServiceModel.ClientBase subclass](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38953/thread-safe-wrapper-around-wcf-servicemodel-clientbase-subclass)
- [Secure CURL to & handle response from Payment Gateway](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27755/secure-curl-to-handle-response-from-payment-gateway)

The rest have to do with [shopping-cart](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping-cart) and [validation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/validation).

I don't believe the questions above have enough content specifically related to payment systems to make the tag worthwhile.

Comment: Wrong Wikipedia article. [E-commerce payment system](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=E-commerce_payment_system).