# Do we have some rebel tags that shouldn't exist on Code Review?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just found a question with [finance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) and there are 45 questions tagged with it.  what does that have to do with code review?

---

This led me to the Tags page and I found a few that look out of place

- [arguments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arguments) -> could be [parameters](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parameters)?  or not (it doesn't exist)
- [adventure-game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure-game)
- [asynctask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asynctask) -> **note** I just retagged the only 3 questions with [asynchronous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asynchronous)
- [autoloader](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autoloader)
- [contextmenu](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contextmenu) -> I added a tag wiki for that.
- [connection-pool](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connection-pool)
- [covariance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariance) probably a good tag that just isn't used often, no wiki.
- [data-importer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-importer)
- [device-driver](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/device-driver) re-tag as [drivers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drivers) and add a wiki?
- [elasticsearch](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) I think we have a tag for Search algorithms, don't we? maybe this should be synonymized
- [erb](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erb) I am sure this means something to someone, probably just needs a wiki.
- [etl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etl) Same as [erb](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erb)
- [freetype](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freetype)

I am sure that there are more, but this is as far as I have gotten so far.

I think we should look through the tags and clean them up a little bit.

Comment: [Discussion around the more specific game tags](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/game-tag-when-to-create-own-tag-for-games).

Comment: I recommend that each tag (or at least small groups of related tags) get their own meta questions. Talking about large groups of tags all at once [tends to degenerate into a larger confusing discussion.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/should-we-do-something-about-our-meta-tags#comment5495_2024).

Comment: these mostly need either Burnination or Wikination @RubberDuck

Comment: [Burn Request for ETL](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/should-we-drop-etl)

Comment: [tag:erb] is a [Ruby class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html). Meta pending.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was a good bit of [discussion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2244/41243) around [finance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance). What does finance have to do with a code review? Well, nothing really. It does however help to ***categorize*** the types of code in the questions we receive.

From [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/tagging):

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question.
>   Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be
>   able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined
>   categories.
>
> **Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are
>   interesting or relevant to you.**

Emphasis mine.

Tags are not just for separating the different kinds of technology we use. They are for connecting people to the questions that interest them. Financial programming is definitely an area of expertise. There are many things that may trip up someone who is not an expert in the field. The [finance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) tag helps connect experts in the field to these questions. This expertise is often language agnostic, hence a language agnostic tag.

Answer (score 2):

@RubberDuck already said that the tags do not have to relate to code review explicitly (in which case we would need to delete a lot more tags, like [array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/array), [linked-list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-list), [sorting](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting), etc). So the question is if these tags are used, or at least could be used.

I think that most of those tags make a lot of sense, and if you search for them, there are quite a few results:

- [arguments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arguments): [1,077 results](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=arguments+is%3Aquestion) + [1,272 results](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=parameters+is%3Aquestion) for parameters (a bit generic, but some of those fit in this tag quite well)
- [adventure-game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure-game): [24 results](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=adventure+game+is%3Aquestion)
- [asynctask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asynctask): [31 results](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=asynctask+is%3Aquestion)
- [autoloader](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autoloader): [40 results](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=autoloader+is%3Aquestion) + [45 results](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=class+loader+is%3Aquestion) for class loader
- [contextmenu](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contextmenu): [9 results](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=contextmenu+is%3Aquestion)
- [covariance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariance): [15 results](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=covariance+is%3Aquestion)
- [elasticsearch](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch): [5 results](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=elasticsearch+is%3Aquestion)

Some of the other ones are either hard to search for or actually don't have that many questions.

But I think for most of these tags it's not that they shouldn't exist, but that they should be used more.

Comment: maybe AsyncTask should be Synonymized with Asynchronous?

Comment: Arguments with Parameter to create a new tag entirely...?

Comment: @Malachi `AsyncTask` is a concrete Android class (I edited the wiki to reflect this), while the `Asynchronous` tag is for the general concept. I would leave it as it is, but add a wiki description and probably add the tag to lot of questions where it's missing right now.

Comment: `AsyncTask` means an Asynchronous task, even when made into an Android class it's still Asynchronous and we have that tag already, and anyone dealing with Android will most likely know when someone talks Asynchronous and Android that they are going to be using the `AsyncTask` class/library.  right? wrong?

Comment: @Malachi not necessarily. `AsyncTask` isn't the only option in Android (and the second result when googling for `AsyncTask` is `AsyncTask is bad and you should feel bad`, so I think it's save to say that at least some people prefer different ways to handle asynchronous code execution in Android, like a Service).

Comment: @tim I filtered answers out of the searches you posted. I also updated the result numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I created [arguments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arguments) for this question: [Is it possible to write reusable method that only some of its parameters are different?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/67436/41243)

The question directly relates to the use of arguments, hence the tag. Should I have run it through meta first? Maybe I should have, but I've always been one that would rather beg for forgiveness than ask for permission. I have the power to create new tags and I felt it was a good tag, so I added it. We're all citizen moderators after all.

I would use this for questions along these (hypothetical) lines.

> - Am I passing too many parameters to my constructor?
> - How can I clean up this method signature?

Or this very real example, [Handling null arguments in a factory class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40559/handling-null-arguments-in-a-factory-class).

Now, all of that said, if the community disagrees that this is a good tag. I will personally remove it.

---

**Update:**

There was a [meta specifically about the arguments tag](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3713/41243). It was decided that it is not a good tag and I have removed it from the only question using the tag.

Comment: Parameters and Arguments are really the same thing...tomato, potato, right?

Comment: [Not technically the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1788926/3198973), but close enough for the purposes of a tag. I would actually suspect we would create parameter as a synonym if this tag stays.

Comment: so it's like input/output or argument/parameter, well not really.  it's a hand off at the door by the pizza man.

Comment: A parameter is the *variable*, an argument is the value passed to the parameter. In reality though, most people use the words interchangeably (right or wrong).