# Should we Drop [ETL]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

[etl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etl) currently has no wiki and three questions. It was [mentioned that it may be a rebel tag](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3673/do-we-have-some-rebel-tags-that-shouldnt-exist-on-code-review).

For those that don't know, ETL is an acronym for [**Extract-Transform-Load**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) and is a term heard often in the database world. The problem I foresee is that you could potentially tag 50% or more of the [sql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) questions with this tag. There also seems to be a misconception at large about what ETL actually is. Only [one of the three](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13057/etl-code-to-synchronize-external-system-to-internal-database) currently tagged questions even comes close to involving ETL.

Should we <s>burn</s> `Drop` [etl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etl)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the use of the [etl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etl) tag on

- [ETL code to synchronize external system to internal database](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13057/etl-code-to-synchronize-external-system-to-internal-database)
- [MergeUtility for Entity Framework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11231/is-my-mergeutility-good-enough-to-create-an-open-source-project-out-of)

The use here is marginal

- [Extract data from one column of SQL Server table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30361/extract-data-from-one-column-of-sql-server-table)

but not entirely inappropriate, if that is how the author prefers to think of the problem.

I would just let the tag continue to exist and add a description and tag wiki.

Comment: [I added the tag wiki](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/etl/info).