# Wiki for [finance] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I think that now we have an overlapping tag for everything to do with finance ([thanks to @200_Success](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/do-we-need-a-payment-system-tag#comment6578_2245)'s comment on [Do we need a [payment-system] tag?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2244/18427))

We need to decide what the description should be so that people aren't just adding this tag all willy-nilly.

What should it be?